# Web Analytics for Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, web-analytics

I am contemplating google analytics, but my problem with it is that I don't own my data. The data is always stored in google's server, and I also I don't really trust their scripts (They probably collect more data than the analytics require)

I read about piwik but its for mySQL only, and heroku uses postgreSQL.

all web analyitics software I found is either for php or mySQL.

Besides, google analytics, what is a good solution for getting user's analytics on heroku and PG? I wish there was a heroku add-on for that..

Comment: It might be worth bugging Heroku about that - if they see much demand they might find it worth porting one of the MySQL-only options to Pg.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still wondering, you can use ClearDB, a Heroku add-on that offers a MySQL database-as-a-service product if you really want to use Piwik on Heroku.

https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb